# JQuery returns same charcode for capitals and lowercase

Tags: jquery

i have attached this function to the key pressed event with jquery but in the eventObject it returns the same char code for capitals and lower case characters entered

```
function keyPressed(delegates,eventdata){
        var keyType = new KeyType();
        var keycode = eventdata.which;
        if((keycode === 0)&&(eventdata.keyCode === 46)){
            keycode=46;
        }
        switch(keycode)
        {
        case keyType.enter:
            break;
        case keyType.backspace:
            break;
        case keyType.del:
            break;
        case keyType.space:
            break;
        default:
            keycode = 1;
        }
        console.log(eventdata.charCode);
        console.log(eventdata.which);
        console.log(eventdata.keyCode);
        //if a delegate is present call it
        var delegate = delegates[keycode];
        if(delegate !== null){
            delegate(eventdata);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use [`.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)? What's the problem? What did you expect? You only stated that you're experiencing that method's expected behavior, there's no question at all.

Comment: output from the following snippet for the letter a and the letter A

  console.log(eventdata.charCode);
  console.log(eventdata.which);
  console.log(eventdata.keyCode);

0
65
65

Comment: And that function runs on `keydown` or `keypress` event? There are inconsistencies between different browsers, you should use `.which` to get a normalized output in all events across all browsers.

Comment: i can run it of the which event... this is running off the keydown event

Comment: thanks to you coomment of keydown or keypress i found the solution. i registered for the keydown event and it gave incorrect values for which. i then registered for the keypress event and it gives the correct ones. you can add this as the answer and ill mark it as correct for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using jQuery to detect keyboard/mouse events, you should always use [`event.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) to get the normalized user input cross-browser.

Slightly off-topic illustrative history, couple months ago I made an userscript in Vanilla JS which runs perfectly fine in FF and Chrome, and just now I had a report that it wasn't working in Opera. I quickly debugged it on Opera and of course, the `event.keyCode` was returning `0` when it should be the key's value.

So yes, whenever you can use jQuery's [`event.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) to handle user-input, use it to save a lot of headaches.

`keydown` and `keypress` are different events and as such may report different values for different events -- which may differ further into having a `keyCode` and/or `charCode` properties in different browsers. `event.which` minimizes those discrepancies.

Answer (score 1):

The char code indicates the key that is pressed. Your keyboard only has one key for both "a" and "A".  You need to also examine the shift key:

```
  if (eventData.shiftKey) {
    //Shift
  }
  if (eventData.ctrlKey) {
    //Ctrl
  }
  if (eventData.altKey) {
    //Alt
  }
```

Comment: and what if caps is on?... i also noticed it returns strange things for special chars

eg

<>,.?/"':;{[}]\|

outputs as 

¼¾¼¾¿¿ÞÞ;;ÛÛÝÝÜÜCC